# How do you evaluate tan(1+i)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm a little confused how to evaluate the tangent function with complex numbers. I know $\tan(1+i)=\sin(1+i)/\cos(1+i)=(e^{-1+i}-e^{1-i})/(i(e^{-1+i}+e^{1-i})$.The book says the answer is $(\sin(2)+i\sinh(2))/(\cos(2)+\cosh(2))$.not sure how they get the final form.any suggestions?

Comment: What is "THE BOOK"? Have you multiplied wiht the complex conjugate of the denominator and used the definition of $\sinh $ and $\cosh$?

Comment: The book is applied complex analysis by Nakhle Asmar

Comment: Write out your answer using DeMoivre's law and it should convert into the book's answer

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}=-i\sinh ix$$
$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}=\cosh ix$$ 
Replace $x$ by $ix$ and obtain $\sin ix, \cos ix$ interms of $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x.$
$$\sin(x+iy)=?$$
$$\cos(x+iy)=?$$

Comment: I get cos(1+i)=cos(1)cosh(1)-isin(1)sinh(1) and sin(1+i)=sin(1)cosh(1)+icos(1)sinh(1)

Comment: @James: multiplied with the complex conjugate of the  denominator then you will get the answer.

Comment: Is there any site where I might see an example of one like this done in steps?

Answer (score 0):

If $\tan(a+ib)=x+iy, \tan(a-ib)=x-iy$

$2x=\tan(a+ib)+\tan(a-ib)=\dfrac{\sin(a+ib+a-ib)}{\cos(a+ib)\cos(a-ib)}=\dfrac{\sin2a}{\cos^2a-\sin^2(ib)}$

$2iy=\tan(a+ib)-\tan(a-ib)=\dfrac{\sin[a+ib-(a-ib)]}{\cos(a+ib)\cos(a-ib)}=\dfrac{\sin2ib}{\cos^2a-\sin^2(ib)}$

Now, $\sin(ib)=\dfrac{e^{i(ib)}-e^{-i(ib)}}{2i}=-i\dfrac{e^{-b}-e^b}2=i\sinh(b)$